# SWT TreeViewer is slow to expand a node with thousend of children

Tags: java, treeview, swt, jface

I have a FilteredTree, and one node contains 10000 children. Expanding that node for the first time takes about 60 seconds. After that it's almost instant. My guess it's that it redraws the tree for each children. Is there a way to make the redraw happen only once after the node was clicked to expand and all treeItems were created ?

Comment: The `Tree` has a `setRedraw` method that you can call. But expanding a large tree can still be slow, you may need to use a virtual tree with SWT.Virtual and ILazyTreeContentProvider

Comment: When the user expands a node, `TreeItem` is created and the `setText` method calls a redraw on the `Tree`. So, `setRedraw` to false on the `Tree` is pointless since the first tree item that is created overrides that.

Comment: No, the setRedraw prevents the setText draw from happening immediately. on macOS, for example, it sets a flag in the OS to stop draws happening. Note that some of the TreeViewer expand APIs already disable redraw.

Comment: Well, I called `treeViewer.getTree().setRedraw(false);` after creating the Tree. But when I expand a node, the `Tree.redraw` gets called from `TreeItem.setText` which sets the redraw flag back to true.

Comment: I'm looking at the macOS code which works as I described and is the intended behaviour. The internal code of Tree/TreeItem is different on each platform so it may be different on your platform. Anyway for your case you certainly need to use a virtual tree as then only the visible items will be created.

Comment: Yes, you're probably right. I'm using windows. Will try to use virtual tree to see if it helps.